# How can I get the Response body from HttpServletResponse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I want to get the Response body during Post HandlerInterceptor but it comes up empty.

**spring-boot.version: 2.7.4**

**CustomPostHandlerInterceptor.java**

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class CustomPostHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public final boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public final void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper resp = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        byte[] responseBody = resp.getContentAsByteArray();
        String res = new String(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    @Override
    public final void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            Exception ex) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/exampleRest")
public class ExampleRest {


    @RequestMapping("/getUsername")
    @GetMapping
    public String getUsername() {
        return "michael";
    }
}
```

I want to get response body from HttpServletResponse.
I tried different methods but it comes up empty.
How can I fix?

Comment: have you tried calling ````resp.copyBodyToResponse();```` after ```String res = new String(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Have you added a filter which caches your response in the first place? Try extending the OncePerRequestFilter and create a ContentCachingResponseWrapper for your response.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the response can only be read once so you need to copy it.

You need a filter as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LogFilter extends HttpFilter {
    private FilterConfig filterConfigObj;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfigObj = config;
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletResponseCopier responseCopier = new HttpServletResponseCopier((HttpServletResponse) response);

        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, responseCopier);
            responseCopier.flushBuffer();
        } finally {
            byte[] copy = responseCopier.getCopy();
            System.out.println(new String(copy, response.getCharacterEncoding()));
        }
    }
}
```

And these dependent classes to read and preserve the response.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;

public class HttpServletResponseCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private ServletOutputStreamCopier copier;

    public HttpServletResponseCopier(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(outputStream);
        }

        return copier;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            copier = new ServletOutputStreamCopier(getResponse().getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            copier.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        if (copier != null) {
            return copier.getCopy();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.WriteListener;

public class ServletOutputStreamCopier extends ServletOutputStream {

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream copy;

    public ServletOutputStreamCopier(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(b);
        copy.write(b);
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        return copy.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only method that has reliably worked for me, I now need a request copier also as the ContentCachingRequestWrapperis not working properly with HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cache the response in the first place, you can extend the OncePerRequestFilter from spring and then cache your response, the following code registers a filter that creates a ContentCachingWrapper for your request and response, using this you should be able to get the response using the code that you have mentioned.

```
@Component
@Order(-999)
public class ContentCachingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        var cachedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request), cachedResponse);
        } finally {
            cachedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but in my case I did set the filter as: ```val wrappedResponse = ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response)
        filterChain.doFilter(ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request), wrappedResponse)
        wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse()```

Comment: This isn't working for me despite the filter chain being hit ok first (you've missed 'new' before ContentCachingResponseWrapper also).

Comment: Thanks @Mark for the review comments, I have now updated my answer, can you check and see if this works?

Comment: @SputNick i've had to implement my own wrapper using John Williams answer, I could not ready the body and pass it down the chain, it has to be copied into a new input stream. I'm having to do the same with the request body also, I simply cannot get these Spring wrappers to give me the content and pass them on reliably, it's a trivial pattern that I assume is implemented this way for efficiency as http requests clearly need to be super fast and not clogging garbage collection.